# Can't connect to mongo replica set running on docker containers

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a running mongo replica set deployed via docker compose. Additionally, I exposed all the replica members:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:5.0.8
    volumes:
      - ~/mongors/data1:/data/db
      - ./rs-init.sh:/scripts/rs-init.sh
    networks:
      - mongors-network
    ports:
      - 27021:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "dbrs" ]
  mongo2:
    container_name: mongo2
    image: mongo:5.0.8
    volumes:
      - ~/mongors/data2:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongors-network
    ports:
      - 27022:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "dbrs" ]
  mongo3:
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo:5.0.8
    volumes:
      - ~/mongors/data3:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongors-network
    ports:
      - 27023:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "dbrs" ]

networks:
  mongors-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Now, I want to insert some data with simple python script, by connecting to the rs using a script located outside of docker:

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGO_REPLICA_SET_ADDRESS = "mongodb://localhost:27021,localhost:27022,localhost:27023/?replicaSet=dbrs"


def main():
    mongo_client = MongoClient(MONGO_REPLICA_SET_ADDRESS)

    # do some health checks
    mongo_client.server_info()

    data_col = mongo_client["myDB"]["myCol"]
    with open('data.json') as d:
        simple_data = json.load(d)
        data_col.insert_many(simple_data)
        print("Successfully inserted {} documents".format(len(simple_data)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but then I'm getting the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo1:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo2:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo3:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 629dc136f14696539a801ade, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongo1', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo1:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, <ServerDescription ('mongo2', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo2:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, <ServerDescription ('mongo3', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo3:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>]>
```

This is my docker ps (looks like they should be accessible from localhost):

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                           NAMES
51ff0f2b4b99   mongo:5.0.8   "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   5 days ago       Up 5 days       0.0.0.0:27022->27017/tcp, :::27022->27017/tcp   mongo2
aafa85aa4bca   mongo:5.0.8   "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   5 days ago       Up 5 days       0.0.0.0:27021->27017/tcp, :::27021->27017/tcp   mongo1
7c9954544e1b   mongo:5.0.8   "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   5 days ago       Up 5 days       0.0.0.0:27023->27017/tcp, :::27023->27017/tcp   mongo3
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hello, did you fix this problem? Please can you your solution here?